# Populating a navbar with dynamic content on every page

Tags: twig, sculpin

I'm building a blog-like template using Sculpin, and need to populate a sidebar with categories. This sidebar is supposed to be visible on every page. However, Layouts don't seem to interpret YAML frontmatters like Sources do. This makes it problematic to create a globally visible menu that gets populated based on the content data (eg. posts).

I can reference `data.posts_categories` if the current Source's YAML frontmatter has:

```
---
use:
    - posts_categories
---
```

and I'm fine with just putting it in every Source file. However, there are also Views (like "post.html"), which again do not support YAML information.

[Based on this post](http://yottaram.com/blog/2014/03/02/static-site-generation-with-sculpin/), apparently you can declare a list of properties. However this apparently only allows to declare constants.

In other words: I need to be able to reference posts and categories in layouts (in the master template). Is there a way to do that, or something similar?

Comment: any luck with solution?

Comment: Yep, switched to a technology more suitable for the task :) Sculpin is not at all designed for any kind of dynamic content.